# How to accept list of marks to get output in form of table describing grades

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having trouble in formulating a python code which will accept a list of marks from the user and then the output is shown in table (rows and columns) format describing grade (letter) and description.

For example: if user enters marks of 90 and 60, output should be column (mark, grade, description) and row (as 90, A+, excellent).

I am new to the world of python.

Comment: What have you tried that hasn't worked?

Comment: [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) might be what you're looking for. You can [get started here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/getting_started/index.html).

Comment: I have tried the if else loop but I am not getting the output in a table format with it.

Comment: I am using visual editor. Can pandas work with it ? Thanks

Comment: Please copy and paste what you have already tried...

Comment: I have tried this

Comment: input_string= input("Enter your marks: ")
user_list = input_string.split()
print("list: ", user_list)

for i in range(len(user_list)):
    user_list[i] = int(user_list[i])

Answer (score 0):

I am not going to write the code for you because it seems like an academic problem. To accept a list of marks, you simply need to use the split function. I will let you figure that out. Make sure you change the list (after the split function) into integer or float so that you can work on them.

To get output in table form, use pandas or tabulate.

Figure things out like that. You will learn more. Good luck

Comment: Thanks. It worked like a charm. Though I am still figuring out pandas. 

Thanks again. Will heed to your advice

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).